# OpenCV Error: Unspecified Error(The Function is not implemented)

Tags: python, c++, opencv, opencv3.1, imshow

OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 545
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:545: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage

**How to solve this? It seems error in openCV 3.2.0 .** Now even in 3.1.0 is showing same error. Anyone please help.

Comment: _Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script_

Comment: @Miki This is same as mentioned in Error itself. Please tell how to do it.

Comment: Same problem, fixed by going [here](http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get purge python-opencv
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```